# SQL Connection string issue when deploying ASP.NET Core MVC to Azure App Service (Linux)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I have created a simple ASP.NET Core MVC application using EF Core and SQL Server. On the Windows development machine it is using localdb. I am trying to deploy to Azure App Service (Linux). I have created an Azure SQL database. Deploying from Visual Studio 2019, I have set the database as a dependency. In the publish profile settings I have selected the Azure SQL connection string for the database context I am using. I have also checked the EF Migrations and on deployment the script successfully created the tables for the application. I can connect to Azure SQL and see the tables. However when I run the deployed application and try a database operation I get: PlatformNotSupportedException: LocalDB is not supported on this platform

I can see from the docs various ways to set the connection string but I would like to know what the publish wizard in Visual Studio 2019 is trying to do and why it is not working? I'm also unclear where the password is stored. In the publish profile the password seems to be in the connection string as plain text, not good. I'd like to know how to get this right for production.

**Update** I have fixed this for the moment by following the steps in the Linux tutorial, using the Azure CLI and running the following command:

az webapp config connection-string set --resource-group [myResourceGroup] --name [app name] --settings MyDbConnection='[connection-string]' --connection-string-type SQLServer

I am not sure of the security of this approach and plan to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

The publish wizard simply handles the database creation/migration for you, it doesn't modify your project, as that's 1) not its purpose and 2) it can't make the configuration decision for you (i.e. use appsettings, environment variables, etc.)

You need to provide the connection string in production via configuration, just as in development. Since you're deploying to an Azure App Service, the most logical place for that would be to the App Settings in the Azure. These will be loaded in via environment variables. Simply specify the same key you're using in development and specify the production database target there.

Comment: I did wonder if that was the case but there's no such step in the tutorial here, it just seems to work magically. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase